# pytorch cnn stride error

Tags: python, pytorch, stride, conv-neural-network

I am now using pytorch 0.4.0 in windows to build a CNN and here is my code:

```
class net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(1,3),stride=1 )

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(1,3), stride=1)

        self.dense1 = nn.Linear(32 * 28 * 24, 60)
        self.out = nn.Linear(60,3)

    def forward(self, input):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(input))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1) # flatten（batch，32*7*7）
        x = self.dense1(x)
        output = self.out(x)
        return output
```

but I get the **error** that

```
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 301, in forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)

RuntimeError: expected stride to be a single integer value or a list of 1 values to match the convolution dimensions, but got stride=[1, 1]
```

I think it shows that I made some mistakes in the code above, but I don't know how to fix it, can any one help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When is your error produced? I cannot reproduce it, neither in the forward nor the backward pass.

Comment: I have the same problem (Anaconda, Python 3.6, pytorch 0.4.0) after saving the model and then reloading it.

Comment: Okay, so for me it was missing the batch dimension when I was feeding a single item. See [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/expected-stride-to-be-a-single-integer-value-or-a-list-of-1-values-to-match-the-convolution-dimensions-but-got-stride-1-1/17140).

Comment: I found out that is because of my input data type, my data should be DoubleTensor but I used as FloatTensor, also when the dimension did not match, this error will occur.

Comment: It's totally fine to answer and accept your own question btw., it might help future readers. :)

Answer (score 2):

Fine, maybe I know what's happening cause I've faced same runtime error just 4 or 5 hours ago.

Here is my solution in my case(I defined the dataset by myself):

The image I feed into the net is 1 channel, same as your code(`self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,...)`). And the attribute of the image which would bring runtime error is as followed:

**error_img**

[image]

The image I fixed is as followed:

**fixed_img**

[image]

Can you feel the difference? The input image's channel should be 1, so the `img.shape()`should be tuple! Use `img.reshape(1,100,100)`to fix it and the net's forward function would proceed.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: don't post question to a question as the answer

Comment: @stackfan Edited.Thx for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons could be the `input` fed to the model for processing; `input` must be missing one of the dimensions.

Try [`torch.unsqueeze(input, 0)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze)